# How to fix my error while compiling my C file?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I need some help with my C file.
Here is my code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ft_putchar.c`

Here is the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your program does not have `main`... So it is not really a program.

Comment: You can use `-c` option to have the compiler do compilation only (no linking to executable).